# How to pass a @ContentChild attribute into a story book?

Tags: angular, storybook

I have a component with a @ContentChild attribute.

How can I pass this attribute into a story?

This is the container component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  @ContentChild('mainButton') mainButton?: ButtonComponent;

  constructor() {}
}
```

This is the button component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-atom',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() text?: string;
  @Output() clickHandler = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.text = 'Text';
  }

  protected readonly ButtonType = ButtonType;
}
```

And this is my story:

```
const meta: Meta<HeaderComponent> = {
  title: 'Header',
  component: HeaderComponent,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  render: (args: HeaderComponent) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
  }),

  argTypes: {},
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<HeaderComponent>;

export const header: Story = {
  args: { hasBackButton: true, mainButton: new ButtonComponent() },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
header.stories.ts

export default {
  title: 'Components/Headers',
  component: HeaderComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [ButtonComponent],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;

export const Primary= (whatever) => ({
  component: HeaderComponent,
  template: `<app-header>
  <ng-template> </ng-template>
  </app-header>`,
});
```